# How to handle DMLs on table that has many indexes in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is table which have around 100 columns and 60-70 columns are searchable in any combination on UI.
So we have indexing on all these columns for faster search.
But since postgres is doing reindexing with each insert, update, delete operation, its slowing the insert, update, delete.
So to make insert faster, we need to disable auto reindexing, but have to keep indexes for faster search.

Is there a way in postgres to not run the reindexing on any insert / update/ delete or disable the auto reindexing on insert/update/delete, and rather setup a nightly job runs daily to do the reindexing?

Or is there any better solution to handle the DMLs on the table?

Volume of data in table is > 6 millions.

I know a solution where indexes can be disabled prior to DMLs and enable after DML is done.

Comment: have you considered combined indexes,but 100 columns is very large, can't you redesign your table structure and combine the columns to tables

Comment: Without the DDL and the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for your SQL statements (in plain text), it's hard to see what the real problem is. 6 million records is imho next to nothing, that should not be a problem.

Comment: *I know a solution where indexes can be disabled prior to DMLs and enable after DML is done.* is not a solution it is an admission that your design is flawed. If you want the indexes to be useful they will need to be updated in sync with the table, otherwise you might as well not have them.

Comment: Can you please add the DDL of your table, as well as brief description of use case? If your table is not highly transactional it would make sense to create a copy of existing table without any indexes but only Primary key as a landing zone for your data, and create a trigger that would insert this data into your actual table with indexes. As long as you can live with the x amount of ms for the data to travel from table A to table B this would allow for both fast inserts and fast reads.